# Subtract three rows from an array in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to subtract the first 3 row of the table

`TVA Collectée -TVA Deductible-Tva deductible/immo`

if the difference between them is positive, I want to put the calculated result in the box `TVA à Payer` and if it is negative in the box `Crédit de tva`

This is my html code:

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="styled-table" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
      <thead>
        <tr height="50">
          <th align="center" width="150">&nbsp;</th>
          <td align="center" width="150" *ngFor="let item of listdate">{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <th>TVA Collectée</th>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
            <td>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let c of listTvaVente">
                <label *ngIf="item === c.date">{{c.tvaCollectee | number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
              </ng-container>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>TVA Déductible</th>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
            <td>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let c  of listTvaAchat ">
                <label *ngIf="item === c.date ">{{c.tvaDeductible| number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
              </ng-container>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>TVA Déductible/immo</th>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
            <td>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let c  of listTvaInv ">
                <label *ngIf="item=== c.date ">{{c.tvaDeductible| number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
              </ng-container>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>TVA à Reporter</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>TVA à Payer</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Crédit de TVA</th>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
```

This my .ts code:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  listdate = ['Janvier-2021', 'Février-2021', 'Mars-2021'];
  date = ['2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03'];

  listTvaVente = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaCollectee: 36000.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaCollectee: 35455.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaCollectee: 45000.0
    }
  ];

  listTvaAchat = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaDeductible: 26000.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaDeductible: 26000.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaDeductible: 32000.0
    }
  ];
  listTvaInv = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      tvaDeductible: 12000.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      tvaDeductible: 11500.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      tvaDeductible: 13000.0
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

here is an example I want to do

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to add to your code to have what you want:

```
Typescript:

    listApayer = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      tvaPayer: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      tvaPayer: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      tvaPayer: 0
    }
  ];

  creditTva = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      tvaCredit: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      tvaCredit: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      tvaCredit: 0
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const length = this.listdate.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const subValue =
        this.listTvaVente[i].tvaCollectee -
        this.listTvaAchat[i].tvaDeductible -
        this.listTvaInv[i].tvaDeductible;

      if (subValue >= 0) {
        this.listApayer[i].tvaPayer = subValue;
      } else {
        this.creditTva[i].tvaCredit = subValue * -1;
      }
    }
  }
```

and for .HTML:

```
     <tr>
    <th>TVA à Payer</th>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
      <td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let c  of listApayer ">
          <label *ngIf="item=== c.date ">{{c.tvaPayer| number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Crédit de TVA</th>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
      <td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let c  of creditTva ">
          <label *ngIf="item=== c.date ">{{c.tvaCredit| number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
```

for a live example, please refer to this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-myfas7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: how do I do when subvalue is negative i want to put this value in the box `TVA à reporter`  and the subvalue of the next month will be calculated in this way                                  
` TVA Collectée -TVA Deductible-Tva deductible/immo`     as in the example I mentioned for the month of April

Comment: I've updated the example above. Please check.

Comment: What about the case you have TVA à reporter and Crédit de TVA for the same month? I guess their sum should be added to the  TVA à reporter of the next month, right?

Comment: "for calculation of the next month subvalue is calculated in this way TVA Collectée -TVA Deductible-Tva deductible/immo -Credit de tva" => this part is not clear. you mean "Credit de tva" of which month?

Comment: if in the current month for example `January` the subvalue is negative then this value is added at the box `credit de tva`
for the month after the `credit de tva` value will be moved to `credit à reporté`  as a repoted credit and it will be inclued in the calculation of that month the formula will be `TVA Collectée -TVA Deductible-Tva deductible/immo -TVA a reporter` for the month of february @ab.dev

Comment: ok now we are on the same way. you are confused between TVA a reporter and Credit de tva in your answers. please re-read your answers. but now with "TVA a reporter" sounds logic.

Comment: I've updated the live example. Please check if that what you exactly need https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-myfas7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: sorry i wasn't playing attention u are right

Comment: thank you so much problem solved thanks for all your effort @ab.dev

Comment: When there are missing values in the table the calculation become wrong for example when i don't have values of tva deductible / immo for the two first months  the result is wrong ...could you help me with this as well please ?! Link to the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-s4hphq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts @ab.dev